# Django Query result comparison with if statement

Tags: python, django, if-statement, web, view

Need to check browser changeable values with using browser inspect and enter random id into url which is in button so I'm not really pro about django and stuff.I make a validation of data which is going to updated or deleted that can checked by tenantid for instance Im going press update on a single line of record and mechanics going to check if the record tenantid is equal to my tenant id or not.
problem is about I cant compare query result to int value.

if any better approach about this I'ill be glad to hear, thank you have a good days.

```
@login_required()  def customer_update(request, pk):
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)
    valueOwnerTenantid = Customer.objects.values_list('tenantid',   flat=True).filter(id=pk)
    print(valueOwnerTenantid)
    print(request.user.tenantid)
    print(valueOwnerTenantid.query)

    if number(valueOwnerTenantid) == number(request.user.tenantid):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print('Equal and POST')
            form = CustomerForm(request.POST, instance=customer)
        else:
            print('Equal and Get')
            form = CustomerForm(instance=customer)
            return save_customer_form(request, form, 'customer_update_partial.html')
    else:
```

Comment: Use `.get(id=pk)` instead of `.filter(id=pk)`.

Comment: you're fetching the same `customer` twice. why don't you just check if `customer.tenantid == request.user.tenantid`?

Answer (score 4):

You are only interested in a single value, not a `QuerySet` of values, so you should use `.get(..)` instead of `.filter()` here. But in fact you can even omit it completely, since you already retrieved the `tenantid` in the `customer`.

Your view thus should look like:

```
@login_required()
def customer_update(request, pk):
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)
    if customer.tenantid == request.user.tenantid:
        # ...
```

that being said, it is rather weird that your store an `id` in your models, and not a `ForeignKey` to some `Tenant` model, etc. Making references without `ForeignKey`s is typically *not* a good idea: it is possible that `tenantid`s do *not* refer to real tenants, for example. Furthermore by default Django will not add an index to the `tenantid` column, making searching for the customer with a given `tenantid` more computationally expensive.

Comment: My head just blowned  that right my customer model has tenantid but I still to get it with querying :(  , it's working. thank you for your advice.

Comment: @BCA: well you get it with the same query as the one you already did. So we did not perform a second query here like in the original code fragment. We "piggyback" on the `get_object_or_404(..)` query.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this if you are looking for records with specific tenant_id

```
my_tenant_id = request.user.tenantid
Customer.objects.filter(tenantid=my_tenant_id)
```

or what Willem Van Onsem suggested for single record

Answer (score 2):

`Customer.objects.values_list('tenantid', flat=True).filter(id=pk)` will return a list instead of a single value. 
It also looks like you're getting the same `Customer` object twice

You can remove the `valueOwnerTenantid = Customer.objects.values_list('tenantid',   flat=True).filter(id=pk)` line and just use `customer.tennantid` to get the `tennantid`

```
if customer.tennantid == request.user.tenantid:
   ...
```